# How to change Microsoft Office 2010 beta key?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-activation, office-2010-beta

I have installed office 2010, using a key that I found on forums on the internet. It said it was used too many times already. But when I try to use the mak key that is on my account, it says that it is invalid. How do I change the key, if a key is still installed and is available for 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open one MS Apps like MS Word  . Go to File >> Help >>

you will find out "Change Product Key".

[image]

Comment: luckily I don't see the same thing because it still says that activation is required. And I can't activate it because the key is already used a hundred times. And the MAK key that microsoft itself gave me is invalid,

Answer (score 0):

You can change it as so:

- *Control Panel ⇨ All Control Panel Items ⇨ Programs and Features*
- Find Office 2010
- Right-click it
- Select *Change*
- Select *Enter a Product Key*