# How do I change non-beta Office 2010 product key?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I found [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/119747/how-to-change-microsoft-office-2010-beta-key), but it's answers doesn't work (see image).

I'd like to change the product key of my non-beta Office 2010. Any advice on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used this before, but it might do the trick

http://www.dkszone.net/change-microsoft-office-20102007-license-product-key-office-key-remover

It can also be done from the programs and features list

http://www.mytechguide.org/2010/06/07/change-product-key-microsoft-office-2010-visio-2010/